# Iterating two lists in a compact way

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a more compact way to write a loop for iterating over two list at once than the following:

```
var listA = new List<string>();
var listB = new List<int>();
foreach (var (itemFromListA, itemFromListB) in listA.Zip(listB, 
        (itemFromListA, itemFromListB)=>(itemFromListA, itemFromListB)){                
   // do something with itemFromListA and itemFromListB
}
```

Typing `(itemFromListA, itemFromListB)` three times seems unnecessarily cumbersome and something like `(itemFromListA, itemFromListB)=>(itemFromListA, itemFromListB)` is too long for just an identity operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 6 allows to omit the second parameter like `listA.Zip(listB)` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))))).

Answer (score 7):

You could just write it like this:

```
foreach (var (a,b) in listA.Zip(listB, ValueTuple.Create))
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZVPIO89278)

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Great solution! Just note that this will create a new enumerator as far as I can see, so doing this for large collections might allocate a lot of garbage post-iteration.

Comment: @Ian As far as I can tell, it doesn't create any additional overhead over what OP was already doing. I do think that SomeBody's answer is probably more efficient overall, though I haven't benchmarked them.

Comment: @Ian H It will create a new enumerator object, but valueTuple is a value type, so it will not cause any heap allocation per-item. So the amount of garbage collection needed should be independent of collection size. It will be a bit slower than a regular for-loop, due to the enumerator overhead, but that would not matter in most cases.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not worse, don't get me wrong. The value type comment is a good point though. Still has my upvote!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.Count && i < listB.Count; i++)
 {
 Console.WriteLine(listA[i]);
 Console.WriteLine(listB[i]);
 }
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, but I think it is more error-prone than a foreach-loop.